# Draw pie chart from orgmode table

Tags: org-mode, r

I'm trying to draw a pie chart from an orgmode table. Let's keep it as simple as possible.

```
#+TBLNAME:kuchen
| 100 | ABC |
|   3 | DEF |
| 123 | XYZ |


#+name: pie-chart (kuchen = kuchen)
#+begin_src R :file pie.png 
pie(kuchen[,1], labels = kuchen[,2])
#+end_src
```

But the resulting pie.png is 0 Bytes, empty.

Error message:

```
Fehler in pie(kuchen[, 1], labels = kuchen[, 2]) : 
  Objekt 'kuchen' nicht gefunden
Ruft auf: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> pie
Ausführung angehalten
```

Translation: error in pie, object 'kuchen' not found, calls  ->  -> pie, execution halted

I found this guide: https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html#meta-programming-language . But if I simply copy the example given there into emacs and export it to html, the (in the case of the guide:) dirs.png is 0 Byte = empty as well.

At a first glance, this website seemed very helpful as well:

https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-R/org-R.html

But the given »actions« on a »intable« don't include any »pie« command.

Any ideas how to get a pie chart from an orgmode table?

If the table needed a third column with percentage, no problem. Any solution welcome.

Comment: The variable definition has to be added as a header on the `#+ begin_src` line, *not* on the name line, although that's probably just the first problem: I could not make this work (but I know next to nothing about R).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you need to pass the variable as a `:var` header on the `#+begin_src` line, *not* on the `#+name:` line. But you also need to specify that the results be output to a graphics file. The following worked for me:

```
#+TBLNAME:kuchen
| 100 | ABC |
|   3 | DEF |
| 123 | XYZ |


#+name: piechart
#+begin_src R :results file graphics :file pie.png :var kuchen=kuchen 
pie(kuchen[,1], labels = kuchen[,2])
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: piechart
[[file:pie.png]]
```